# The domain of $\ln x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Define $$\ln x = \int_{1}^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$
>
> Since  $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined at $x = 0$, the range of $\ln x$ is $(0, \infty)$.

According to my textbook, a function is integrable if it has a finite number of discontinuities. Since, $\frac{1}{x}$ has *one* (finite) discontinuity, how can you conclude that $\frac{1}{x}$ in not integrable at $0$ and consequently the domain of $\ln x$ doesn't include 0?

I get that the area of $\frac{1}{x}$ is infinite if integrated at 0, but since it has a finite number of discontinuities, doesn't it still meet the criteria for "integrability?"

So how can you conclude the domain of $\ln x$ is $(0, \infty)$ from the above definition?

Comment: Does your textbook not say something like "a bounded function that has only finitely many discontinuities is integrable"?

Comment: @DanielFischer That definition makes more sense. But why can't you conclude that the domain is x∈ℝ,x≠0 instead of x>0? 1/x is defined and integrable for negative x so how can you assume the domain of 1/x doesn't include negative numbers?

Comment: It's not the domain of $1/x$ that is the problem. But you have a non-integrable singularity in $0$, so the interval of integration must not contain $0$. By definition, the interval contains $1$, so it must lie in the positive half-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct theorem is that a *bounded* function is integrable if it has a finite number of discontinuities. Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is not bounded, the theorem does not apply to it. The integral $\int _0^t\frac{1}{x}dx$ is an improper integral, and thus its existence is the same as the existence of the limit $\lim _{s\to 0+}\int_s^t\frac{1}{x}dx$, but that limit does not exist as a finite real number (it is equal to $\infty$, which is not a number).

Comment: I see. But why can't you conclude that the domain is $x \in \mathbb{R}, x ≠ 0$ instead of $x >0$? $1/x$ is defined and integrable for negative $x$ so how can you assume the domain of $1/x$ doesn't include negative numbers?

Comment: Since $\int_s^t\frac{1}{x}dx$ does not exist for $s<0$ and $t>0$ for the same reason I mentioned above.

Comment: @dfg it's not bounded on $x \in R, x \ne 0$

Comment: @oks How is is not bounded? Don't all $1/x$ for $x ≠ 0$ have a finite value and therefore bounded?

Comment: @dfg Just because they have a finite value doesn't mean they are bounded.  Whatever bound you like, say M, you can find x = 1/(2M) to get 1/(1/2M) = 2M > M.  The function g(x) = x has a finite value for each x, but it is also unbounded.