# Why does a function have to be bounded to be integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand that you can't find the area under a function thats not bounded using Riemann sums, but why can't the function have an antiderivative that is undefined at that point?

Instead of functions not being integrable, if the antiderivative has a discontinuity/is not bounded at the same point, the area still can't be found at that point, but the antiderivative would still be able to be used at other points.

For instance, see [The domain of $\ln x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655176/the-domain-of-ln-x)

The domain of $\ln x$ has to be restricted because otherwise it would contain an unbounded value. Why can't it just have an asymptote like $1/x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens also unbounded function can be "integrable", but I guess you meant the basic definition of Riemann integral (right?), so:

if the function isn't bounded in say $\;[a,b]\;$ then

$$\forall\,M\in\Bbb N\;\;\exists\,x_M\in[a,b]\;\;s.t.\;\;|f(x_M)|>M$$

Now prove that you can construct from the above *a sequence* so that the values of $\;f\;$ on it diverge to $\;\infty\;$ and check what happens with a partition of $\;[a,b]\;$ and its refinements that'll include points from that sequence...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is bit over my head. What do you mean by "the values of $f$ diverge to infinity"?

Comment: I don't think this is over your head at all and you're maybe giving up too fast: you **must** have dealt already with limits of sequence and series in order to reasonably real with Riemann Integral and Riemann Sums, so again: what does it mean a sequence diverges to infinity? Now check again: why do I wrote that the values of $\;f\;$ on the sequence you should have constructed would diverge to infinity?

Comment: Hmmm. Well, if its unbounded then the Riemann integral would diverge (become infinitely large) because the "height" of the rectangles would become infinitely large, since $f$ becomes infinitely large. Is that it?

Comment: As simple as that, @dfg...eventhough you used the geometric picture of the rectangles and not Riemann Sums, but pretty precise anyway.

Comment: But if the antiderivative had a vertical asymptote at that point, wouldn't the divergence of the riemann sum be reflected by that asymptote? So I guess what I'm getting at is, why does a non-bounded function imply non-integrability instead of its antiderivative just having an asymptote?

Comment: Oh, dear: don't mess with antiderivatives *now* before we reach the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus! When dealing with the definition (rectangles, Riemann or Darboux Sums, etc.) we only go by the definition. Besides this, there are integrable function which have no antiderivative (or primitive function, in this context)...

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot!